# Adapt AWS's Mobile React Starter Kit to give Read access to Unauthenticated Users?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, federated-identity, aws-mobilehub

The [AWS Mobile React Starter Kit](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-sample) is great, but it doesn't let users see anything without logging in first.  I'd like to build a web app where unauthenticated users can query parts of the database, but can't make any edits.  I've tried poking around in the AWS configuration, but so far I've only broken the app, not gotten it to do what I want.

**Can anyone advise with the general steps to follow?**

What I've tried:

- Commenting out the first *PublicRoute* element in `/src/index.js`, then modifying the last one to redirect to */main/home* instead of */login*
- Changing [MobileHub configuration of the API](https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home) from *Private* to *Protected*
- [Created a duplicate role](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home) (that I planned to remove write permissions from, once it worked) and [selected it for unauthenticated connections](https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/pool) in Cognito
- Looked around for clues in the *\awsmobilejs* directory of the project folder, without luck

Comment: I see, now, that there's an *UnAuthenticated Requests* header about 2/3 of the way down the project read me.  Looks like I skimmed over that before.  Trying it now.

Comment: Looks like I messed something else up; time to start over.  **BadRequestException: The stack 'arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-1:##########:stack/MOBILEHUB-##########-Development/#####-####-#####-#####' in Amazon CloudFormation has been modified outside of the Mobile Hub. This stage 'Development' can no longer be modified inside of Mobile Hub.**

Comment: Yeah, I started over and followed the instructions under the *UnAuthenticated Requests* header, then changed the *PublicRoute* elements in index.js to redirect to /main/home by default.  I wound up with the same vague error as before: **Error: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.**

Comment: When I try making changes to the Cognito pool, I get this instead (again, as before):  **Error: Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.**

Comment: To read: https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/authentication_guide